# move a word to the end of the line using python

Tags: python, string

I'm parsing an HTML and I'm getting a string of Array that I'm trying to clean it and put in into pdf later. At this level, I would like to move all the words started by `@X` to the end of the line so I could have in the end all the `@X` aligned.

```
Hello World @Xabs
Hello World                                   @Xz
Hello World  @Xss
Hello World         @Xssa
Hello World       @Xqq
Hello World             @Xsasas
```

What I would like to have as an output :

```
Hello World                                        @Xabs
Hello World                                        @Xz
Hello World                                        @Xss
Hello World                                        @Xssa
Hello World                                        @Xqq
Hello World                                        @Xsaxs
```

Any ideas?

What I have so far:

```py
# encoding=utf8 
import sys
reload(sys) 
#import from lxml import html 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import re import codecs 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') 

# Access to the local URL(Html file) f=codecs.open("C:\...\file.html", 'r') 
page = f.read() 
f.close() 

#html 
parsing page_soup = soup(page,"html.parser") 
tree = html.fromstring(page) # extract the important arrays of string 

a_s= page_soup.find_all("td", {"class" :"row_cell"})
for a in a_s:
    result = a.text.replace("@X","")
    print(final_result)
```

Comment: What is an end of the line, is this on the terminal? how long is your line?

Comment: Did you try to solve it on your own? If you've written any code, it would be useful to share with us.

Comment: What's the output format that you want ? An array as well ?

Comment: @David, for the moment I'm deleting the @X and my problematic is about to shift the word just after @X to the end of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite similar to @blue_note's answer, but making the entire solution more automatical:

```
import re

lines = ['Hello World @Xabs',
         'Hello World                                   @Xz',
         'Hello World  @Xss',
         'Hello World         @Xssa',
         'Hello World       @Xqq',
         'Hello World             @Xsasas']

aligned_lines = []
for line in lines:
    match = re.findall('@X\w+', line)[0]
    line = line.replace(match,'')
    aligned_lines.append('%-50s %s' % (line, match))

aligned_lines

['Hello World                                        @Xabs',
 'Hello World                                        @Xz',
 'Hello World                                        @Xss',
 'Hello World                                        @Xssa',
 'Hello World                                        @Xqq',
 'Hello World                                        @Xsasas']
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no specific *line-width* concept in a string. If you want to align your text, print the first part with constant width

```
output = "{:50s} {}".format('preceding text', 'Xword')
```

Comment: I'd not talk about *line-width* but about *line size* or *constant amount of characters*. Talking about width is quite misleading, especially for HTML. Good solution though